# Finding which values are causing RuntimeWarning

Tags: python

I have a function that accepts a big numerical list and then compute something with each value with an equation. However when I run the code I get the following:

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
```

I would like a way to print only the item that is causing the error. How can I do that?

```
def foo(list):
    result = None
    for x in list:
        result = 1/x #makes the warning
    return result
```

Of course `x` would be zero, but I would like to find the index of `x` in the list that is doing this error.

**Edit**: 
is it possible to do that using `try`? or should it be done only using `if`?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code to have if as follows:

```
def foo(list):
    result = None
    for x in list:
        if x==0:
           print "0 found at ", list.index(x)
        else:
           result = 1/x #makes the warning
    return result
```

If we find x is 0, then we print index otherwise we continue with divide

Answer (score 0):

In Python there is a saying: `It's easier to ask forgiveness than it is to get permission` which means that should use a `try/except` block rather than testing for the value of the current integer. 
Also to get the index of any element in an array during iteration without having to use the `index` method you can take a look at [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```
# note that naming your variable 'list' could be dangerous and/or misleading
def foo(integers):
  result = 0
  for (index, current_int) in enumerate(integers):
    try:
      result = 1 / current_int
    except ZeroDivisionError:
      print "Division by zero at index", index
  return result

print foo([1, 23, 0, 7])
# output is 
# Division by zero at index 2
# 0
```